# Installing PostgresSQL on CentOS 6.4 without yum

Tags: installation, centos, postgresql

I've got a company server running CentOS 6.4 on which I'm required to install the tools required for a webapp deployment. One of those tools is PostgreSQL server, however the company VPN is blocking yum and I've been told that "configuring yum to go through company proxy is too difficult" and I've got no authority/ability to do it myself.Thus I'm basically stuck with downloading rpms manually, transfer them over to the server through WinSCP and cross my fingers hoping that `rpm -i` will work.

I've downloaded 3 rpm's:

```
postgresql193-9.3.5.1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
postgresql193-libs-9.3.5.1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
postgresql193-server-9.3.5.1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
```

transferred them over to /usr/local/pgsql and ran `rpm -iv posgresql193-*.rpm`
and got:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) is needed by postgresql93-9.3.5-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64
        libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) is needed by postgresql93-libs-9.3.5-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64
        libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) is needed by postgresql93-libs-9.3.5-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64
        libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) is needed by postgresql93-server-9.3.5-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64
        libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) is needed by postgresql93-server-9.3.5-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64
```

Looking those deps up I've found that they belong to openssl, however running `rpm -qa openssl` I get one match: `openssl-1.0.0-27.el6.x86_64`

So what is going on here? Is the openssl version too low? I've looked for a new centos release of openssl in rpm format and I've got no tangible results. Hopefully I won't have to compile it myself. What do I do?

Oh and by the way, I'm a centos/*nix in general newbie so go easy on me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the openssl version that was too low.

I downloaded the latest openssl rpm for centos from [Linux Packages Search](http://pkgs.org/), updated  openssl and then managed to successfully install postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

The PGDG RPMs aren't standalone - some other dependencies may need to be supplied from the PGDG repo.

**They also require a current RHEL or CentOS point release** AFAIK - so you'll want to be on 6.5. Of course, the usual way to handle the upgrade is with yum...

You need to:

- Mirror the PGDG yum repo locally, with `rsync` or whatever, then point `yum` at your mirror;
- Use `yum` on a box that isn't Internet-crippled to download all the packages you need, then copy them over; or preferably
- Smack your proxy guys upside the head; yum just uses HTTP and there's no way it's hard to configure unless you have the worst proxy in the known universe.

You might be able to convince the firewall guys by invoking the Security Spectre. "The following CRITICAL TERRIBLE OH MY GOD security vulnerabilities were fixed in CentOS 6.5, we need to update IMMEDIATELY! The only way is yum!".

Comment: Agree - call BS on the proxy answer, it's likely completely false and just someone being lazy